# How to prompt user to save downloaded file from Google Drive API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, download

I'm using the Google Ruby API Client to download Google Drive files (with downloadUrl).  I'm able to successfully download the file, but next I want to prompt the Web user to save the file locally (to the location of his choice).  What do I do after the code below to achieve that?

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')

client.authorization.client_id = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
client.authorization.redirect_uri = '...'
client.authorization.access_token = '...'

client.authorization.scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.get,
  :version => 'v2',
  :parameters => { 'fileId' => "..."}
)

download_url = result.data.downloadUrl

if download_url
  fileResult = client.execute(:uri => download_url)
else 
  #HANDLE ERRORS
  ....
end 

# WHAT TO ADD HERE TO PROMPT USER TO SAVE THE FILE LOCALLY?
```

Comment: you can use `send_file` as such `send_file([FILE OBJECT],type: [YOUR MIME TYPE],layout: false, disposition:'attachment')` this will output you file as an attachment to the browser which will prompt the user to open or save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have said in my question that I wanted to do this without saving the file first. Also, part of my question was just how to get the needed info from the download response. Here's what I came up with, which worked:

```
    send_data fileResult.body,  
              :disposition => fileResult.response.env[:response_headers]["content-disposition"], 
              :type => fileResult.response.env[:response_headers]["content-type"]
```